# Merge two dataframes with different length, append to the right R

Tags: r, merge

I have two dataframes

`df1` has 100 rows.

```
> df1
> head1 head2 head3 keyColumn #names of the columns
> ...   ...   ...   ... #content
```

`df2` has 20 rows.

```
> df2
> deah2 deah2 deah3 keyColumn #names of the columns
> ...   ...   ...   ... #content
```

All the rows from `df2` can be matched in `df1`

```
table(df2$keyColumn %in% df1$keyColumn)
> TRUE
> 20
```

My `resultingDataFrame` must have have the same length as `df1` but with all the columns of `df2` attached to right of it.

```
resultingDataFrame
> head1 head2 head3 keyColumn deah2 deah2 deah3 #names of the columns
> ...   ...   ...   ...       ...   ...   ...  #content
> ...   ...   ...   ...       NA    NA    NA #no match
```

I need the names of the columns to be added. But, when the `keyColumn` of `df1` does not appear in `df2` I need the cells filled with `NA` values.

My first idea was to use `merge()` since it allows an `outter`, `inner`, `left` and `right` join.
But, it seems that this is not the right tool.

Naturally there should be 80 rows where all the cells `deah2 deah2 deah3` are filled with `NA`.

The `merge()` appends to the bottom (when something does not match), but not to the side.

Any directions in which to look for a solution?

Comment: Why do you think merge is the wrong tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(id=sample(1:10,5),x=rnorm(5))
df2 <- data.frame(id=sample(1:10,10), y=rnorm(10))
merge(df1,df2, by="id", all=TRUE)
#    id          x          y
# 1   1         NA -1.2375384
# 2   2 -0.2947204 -0.2242679
# 3   3  1.2724293  0.2522234
# 4   4  0.4146414  0.3773956
# 5   5 -1.5399500 -0.2894616
# 6   6         NA  0.4356833
# 7   7 -0.9285670 -0.2992151
# 8   8         NA -0.4115108
# 9   9         NA  0.1333364
# 10 10         NA -0.8919211
```

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df1), id)
setkey(setDT(df2), id)
df1[df2]
```

This latter approach will be *much* faster with large datasets.